# form creates 63 data lines, that have to be writtern to individual rows mysql asp

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp-classic

i have 63 lines of data that have to be written to a database, and was looking for a way to do a loop function. i have a few different pages that act similar to this, so writting 63 mysql statements would be tedious.

i tried using a sql to enter multiple lines, and this was the result: It cannot handle batching (using ; to separate multiple statements) since this would require two way communication. I am afraid you have to do it in a loop and go to database multiple times.

how can i tell it to start at the top, and write all those lines in order.

```
ps11  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"11"),100)
ps12  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"12"),100)
ps13  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"13"),100)
ps21  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"21"),100)
ps22  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"22"),100)
ps23  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"23"),100)
ps31  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"31"),100)
ps32  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"32"),100)
ps33  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"33"),100)
ps41  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"41"),100)
ps42  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"42"),100)
ps43  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"43"),100)
ps51  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"51"),100)
ps52  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"52"),100)
ps53  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"53"),100)
ps61  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"61"),100)
ps62  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"62"),100)
ps63  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"63"),100)
ps71  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"71"),100)
ps72  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"72"),100)
ps73  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10"&pidlocation&"73"),100)


pg11  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"11"),100)
pg12  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"12"),100)
pg13  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"13"),100)
pg21  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"21"),100)
pg22  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"22"),100)
pg23  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"23"),100)
pg31  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"31"),100)
pg32  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"32"),100)
pg33  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"33"),100)
pg41  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"41"),100)
pg42  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"42"),100)
pg43  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"43"),100)
pg51  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"51"),100)
pg52  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"52"),100)
pg53  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"53"),100)
pg61  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"61"),100)
pg62  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"62"),100)
pg63  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"63"),100)
pg71  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"71"),100)
pg72  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"72"),100)
pg73  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20"&pidlocation&"73"),100)


pp11  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"11"),100)
pp12  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"12"),100)
pp13  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"13"),100)
pp21  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"21"),100)
pp22  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"22"),100)
pp23  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"23"),100)
pp31  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"31"),100)
pp32  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"32"),100)
pp33  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"33"),100)
pp41  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"41"),100)
pp42  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"42"),100)
pp43  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"43"),100)
pp51  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"51"),100)
pp52  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"52"),100)
pp53  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"53"),100)
pp61  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"61"),100)
pp62  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"62"),100)
pp63  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"63"),100)
pp71  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"71"),100)
pp72  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"72"),100)
pp73  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30"&pidlocation&"73"),100)




' insert into db
mySQL="INSERT INTO scheduleparts (scheduleid, locationid, dayid, partid, stime, guys, position) VALUES (" & pschedid & ", " & pidlocation & ",1,1,'" &ps11& "', " & pg11 & ", " & pp11 & ")"
call updateDatabase(mySQL, rstemp, "addscheduleform4.asp")
```

Comment: Is this asp classic or asp.net?

Comment: What is the format of the table you are putting the information into?

Answer (score 1):

You should get the querystring values and do the insert within a loop.

You could do something like:

```
arrRequiredIds = Array(11,12,13,21,22,23,31,32,33,41,42,43,51,52,53,61,62,63,71,72,73)

 for each Id in arrRequiredIds

    PSvalue  = getUserInput(request.querystring("10" & pidlocation & CStr(Id)),100)
    PGvalue  = getUserInput(request.querystring("20" & pidlocation & CStr(Id)),100)
    PPvalue  = getUserInput(request.querystring("30" & pidlocation & CStr(Id)),100)

    sql = "INSERT INTO scheduleparts (scheduleid, locationid, dayid, partid, stime, guys, position) "&_
                            " VALUES (" & pschedid & ", " & pidlocation & ",1,1,'" & PSvalue & "', " & PGvalue & ", " & PPvalue & ")"
    Response.write sql & "<br>"
    call updateDatabase(sql, rstemp, "addscheduleform4.asp")
next
```